# Pokemon Go servers go down and I lose all my pokemons

Tags: pokemon-go

This happened earlier.  I guess the servers went down...or maybe I was in an area with no signal, but when I tapped on the app, it started up from the beginning (no longer showing me on the map), had to go thru the dude talking, and then I had to give my nickname.  I put in the same one I used when I registered last night and it allowed it (didn't say it was already in use) and popped me up to create my avatar and sent me on my way...all the ones I caught last night and this morning were gone....anyone know anything about this or how to get back to my orginal avatar?

Comment: How do you log in? I use a google account, and every time there is server outages, it 'forgets' my credentials and I have to re-enter them. Did you log in the second time via a different method?

Comment: It sounds more like the same issue King had. Signing on with a Google+ or Pokemon Trainer Club account are two different things. it's possible you have your old account in one or the other service.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I recovered my account! Here's what I did

*Android devices: From your device's Home screen, visit Settings > Touch Apps or Application Manager > Pokémon GO, and touch Force Stop. Visit Storage and touch Clear Cache.

*iOS devices: From your device’s Home screen, visit Settings > Privacy > Location Services and toggle Pokémon GO off then back on.
*Remove and then reinstall the Pokémon GO app.
*Reboot your device.

I have an iPhone so I followed the directions for iOS device. To reboot aka restart your phone go to settings > general <  restart. This won't delete anything from your phone don't worry! I hope this helps!!!